# How to get overall transaction count of the entire network

Tags: parity, etherscan

I'm running small etherium network on two parity clusters which have no internet connection so `etherscan` is a no-way.

I wonder if it's possible to get overall transaction count via JSON RPC or something. I need to get something like `eth_transactionCount` and get `100500` as result.

How can it be done if it's possible at all?

Comment: How can you run nodes without internet? You mean private network?

Comment: Yes, private network which is not connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this number via web3/JSONRPC, you'll have to iterate over blocks and sum up the transaction counts. See `eth_getBlockTransactionCountByNumber`.